# PHP script to generate a file with random data of given name and size?

Tags: php, file, random

Does anyone know of one? I need to test some upload/download scripts and need some really large files generated. I was going to integrate the test utility with my debug script.

Comment: If there are no scripts readily available, it doesn't seem too trivial to code up one yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To start you could try something like this:

```
function generate_file($file_name, $size_in_bytes)
{
   $data = str_repeat(rand(0,9), $size_in_bytes);
   file_put_contents($file_name, $data); //writes $data in a file   
}
```

This creates file filled up with a random digit (0-9).

Comment: but size won't relate to a given filesize will it?

Comment: $size holds the given file size.

Comment: Didn't realise PHP stored single digit ints as 1 byte. Thx. :)

Comment: @MatW: It doesn't. But it stores a single *character* (as converted to by `str_repeat()`) in 1 byte.

Comment: @NeverEndingQueue: with big files the memoty of the server would be hit. In suchecase you have to use the classic `fopen`, and perform a loop of `fwrite` plus a final `fclose`.

Answer (score 7):

`generate_file()` from "Marco Demaio" is not memory friendly so I created [file_rand()](http://www.programmierer-forum.de/eine-datei-mit-zufaelligem-inhalt-generieren-t339139.htm).

```
function file_rand($filename, $filesize) {
    if ($h = fopen($filename, 'w')) {
        if ($filesize > 1024) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < floor($filesize / 1024); $i++) {
                fwrite($h, bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(511)) . PHP_EOL);
            }
            $filesize = $filesize - (1024 * $i);
        }
        $mod = $filesize % 2;
        fwrite($h, bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(($filesize - $mod) / 2)));
        if ($mod) {
            fwrite($h, substr(uniqid(), 0, 1));
        }
        fclose($h);
        umask(0000);
        chmod($filename, 0644);
    }
}
```

As you can see linebreaks are added every 1024 bytes to avoid problems with functions that are limited to 1024-9999 bytes. e.g. fgets() with <= PHP 4.3. And it makes it easier to open the file with an text editor having the same issue with super long lines.

Comment: If you're generating a random file, why would you possibly want to open it with a text editor?

Comment: @Phil Not only text editors. It could be useful if you read the file line by line through `fgets()` or similar functions to avoid huge memory usage. Of course you can remove this part if you like. I opened it through a text editor to check if the output is as I needed it ;)

Comment: Your function is a little bit buggy. If the given size is a multiple of 1024 or this plus 1, eg. 1024, 1025, 2048, 2049 and so on, your second `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` will have 0 as parameter, and this will lead to an error.

Answer (score 5):

Do you really need so much variation in filesize that you need a PHP script? I'd just create test files of varying sizes via the command line and use them in my unit tests. Unless the filesize itself is likely to cause a bug, it would seem you're over-engineering here...

To create a file in Windows;

```
fsutil file createnew d:\filepath\filename.txt 1048576
```

in Linux;

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=filepath/filename.txt bs=10000000 count=1
```

**if** is the file source (in this case nothing), **of** is the output file, **bs** is the final filesize, **count** defines how many blocks you want to copy.

Comment: `fsutil file createnew` creates an EMPTY FILE, the question is about to create a file with random data.

Answer (score 2):

generate_file() from [@Marco Demaio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2623739/2219158) caused this below when generating 4GB file.

> Warning: str_repeat(): Result is too big, maximum 2147483647 allowed
>   in /home/xxx/test_suite/handler.php on line 38

I found below function from [php.net](http://php.net) and it's working like charm. 
I have tested it upto

> 17.6 TB  (see update below)

in less than 3 seconds.

```
function CreatFileDummy($file_name,$size = 90294967296 ) {   
// 32bits 4 294 967 296 bytes MAX Size
    $f = fopen('dummy/'.$file_name, 'wb');
    if($size >= 1000000000)  {
        $z = ($size / 1000000000);       
        if (is_float($z))  {
            $z = round($z,0);
            fseek($f, ( $size - ($z * 1000000000) -1 ), SEEK_END);
            fwrite($f, "\0");
        }       
        while(--$z > -1) {
            fseek($f, 999999999, SEEK_END);
            fwrite($f, "\0");
        }
    }
    else {
        fseek($f, $size - 1, SEEK_END);
        fwrite($f, "\0");
    }
    fclose($f);

return true;
}
```

## Update:

I was trying to hit 120TB, 1200 TB and more but filesize was limited to 17.6 TB. After some googling I found that it is `max_volume_size` for [ReiserFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReiserFS) file system which was on my server. 
May be PHP can handle 1200TB also in just few seconds. :)

Comment: This seems very impossible to write that much data in 3 seconds. What sort of hardware is this hosted on?

Comment: @pcnate it was private server, hosted on wiredtree.

Comment: This creates a file filled with nulls, which is a special case - it's a "sparse file". Some filesystems treat these specially, can manipulate them extremely fast, and can avoid allocating any storage to them. With Gnu `dd` you can essentially instantly create a 17.6TB sparse file with `dd of=filename bs=1k seek=17600000000 count=0` -
 via https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file

Answer (score 1):

Why not have a script that streams out random data? The script can take parameters for file size, type etc.

This way you can simulate many scenarios, for example bandwidth throttling, premature file end etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

Does the file really need to be random?  If so, just read from /dev/urandom on a Linux system:

`dd if=/dev/urandom of=yourfile bs=4096 count=1024` # for a 4MB file.

If it doesn't really need to be random, just find some files you have lying around that are the appropriate size, or (alternatively) use `tar` and make some tarballs of various sizes.

There's no reason this needs to be done in a PHP script: ordinary shell tools are perfectly sufficient to generate the files you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you want really random data you might want to try this:

```
$data = '';
for ($byteSize-- >= 0) {
    $data .= chr(rand(0,255));
}
```

Might take a while, though, if you want large file sizes (as with any random data).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a library like [Faker](https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker) to generate test data.

Answer (score 0):

I took the answer of *mgutt* and shortened it a bit. Also, his answer has a little bug which I wanted to avoid.

```
function createRandomFile(string $filename, int $filesize): void
{
    $h = fopen($filename, 'w');
    if (!$h) return;

    for ($i = 0; $i < intdiv($filesize, 1024); $i++) {
        fwrite($h, bin2hex(random_bytes(511)).PHP_EOL);
    }

    fwrite($h, substr(bin2hex(random_bytes(512)), 0, $filesize % 1024));

    fclose($h);
    chmod($filename, 0644);
}
```

Note: This works only with PHP >= 7. If you really want to run it on lower versions, use `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` instead of `random_bytes` and `floor($filesize / 1024)` instead of `intdiv($filesize, 1024)`.